# POSIX Thread synchronisation

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

Hi friends i am here with a problem of thread synchronization.I am very new to thrading thats why seek help from you people.
In my code i have to read data from the serial port and then send the data to UDP port. For this i have two extra threads. In the first thread i am reading data in infinite while loop and in the second thread i am doing some processings and then sending.

The problem is that the  i  am not getting the value of buff1[0] whose integral value is== 1 in the second thread properly means i get the value ==1 very rarely. But in the first thread  i am continiously getting the value of buff1[0].

I doubt this is because i have not used mutex lock. I want to know how i will use mutex if it is necessary, in my code. Plz guide me in improving my source code
 Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include "CapSerial.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<time.h>
//this portion added for thread
#include <pthread.h>
#include "lcd_api.h" 

struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock; 
void *serial1Thread();
void *serial2Thread();
char buff1[1024];
int sd,min,sec,hr;
int datalen;
char finalbuf[30];
static int serial1_status=0,serial2_status=0;
char serial1[16],sendbuff[16];    
int fd_lcd ,min,sec,hr,ret,secsend,minsend;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr,cliaddr1;


char serial2[16],serial1[16]; 
char sec_buf[3],min_buf[3],hr_buf[3];
char sec_send[3],min_send[3],hr_send[3];
char sec_buf[3],min_buf[3],hr_buf[3];
int sockfd,n,i,sockfd1;
int fd1,fd2,i,ret1,ret2,ret3;



    int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {                        
     pthread_t thread1,thread2; 
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
     bzero(&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr)); 

        cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.111.4.100");   
        cliaddr.sin_port = htons(1229);  

        ret1=pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,serial1Thread,NULL);         
        ret3=pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,serial2Thread,NULL); 

        pthread_join(thread1,NULL);                   
        pthread_join(thread2,NULL);

     return 0;
    }





void *serial1Thread()
{


               fd1 = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);  
                if (fd1 == -1) 
                {
                perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS1 - ");
                return 0;
                } 
                else 
                {
                 fcntl(fd1, F_SETFL, 0);
                }

                 initport(fd1, 9600);
                 printf("baud=%d\n", getbaud(fd1));


        while(1)
        {      

            // Reading Data in infinite while loop 
              if(readport(fd1, buff1))
                         {
                            printf("Read Error happened \n");
                            exit(0);
                         }
                    else
                      {                        
                        printf("\n The value of buff1[0]=%d",buff[0]);     
                      }        

        }


}



         void *serial2Thread()
          {     

           while(1)
           {   

           printf("\n The value of buff1[0]=%d",buff[0]);                
           sendto(sockfd,sendbuff,14,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));

           }   

         }
```

The problem is that the value of buff1[0] which is SOH(Start of heading) whose integeral
value==1 is not available in second thread every time.

Comment: If I might add, you can do this task trivially without threads using [mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) then [splice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) to make an intervening buffer then just splice the UDP port to the serial port, the kernel will take it from there and do the entire job...

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has no idea that your variables are used in multiple contexts. For doing this you have to use a dedicated thread synchronization with atomics, ipc-calls, message queues, mutex or whatever.

A actual pc runs multiple cores with multiple caches and most data is held somewhere in registers and so on. If you have no manual synchronisation between threads, data will not be synchronsized.

Using `volatile`will NOT help.

So please read about ipc and thread synchronization, e.g. mutex and atomics.